# Installing EasyPHP Devserver14.1 VC11 on Windows 7

Tags: c#, php, visual-c++, windows-7, easyphp

I have used Easy PHP dev server VC9 for ages and it works fine. I need to upgrade to VC11 to get PHP 5.6 but when I try and do so I get the message:

the program can't start because msvcr110.dll is missing

I googled this and found that this means visual studio is missing, (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr110dll-is/f052d325-3af9-4ae5-990b-b080799724db) so I followed the link to the microsoft page and downloaded visual C from the website (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784). Hoever I still get the error.

Thanks for reading, if anyone has any ideas what might be happening, I have tried every other version of Visual C I can find!

Edit: I have had no luck on this, is there any reason why the new version would not work when version 9 works its annoying to have to give up on such a usefull tool! but if I cant use the latest PHP I cant see another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well it looks like the best solution to this problem is to use a different WAMP!